# Saving Many2Many relationships using Flask with SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sql, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm using Flask with SQLAlchemy. I have events and they have tags associated with them. Tags can belong to many events and events can have many tags. I've got three tables, events, tags and event_tag which is a joining table. I can retrieve my data fine - including retrieving the associated tags, but I can't seem to update the Tags that are associated with the Event.

I have the following setup:

```
...

event_tag = db.Table('event_tag',
    db.Column('tag_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('tag.id')),
    db.Column('event_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('event.id'))
)
class Event(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(255))
    note = db.Column(db.Text())
    link = db.Column(db.String(255))
    date_from = db.Column(db.Date())
    date_to = db.Column(db.Date())
    milestone = db.Column(db.Boolean)
    tags = db.relationship('Tag', secondary=event_tag, backref=db.backref('events', lazy='dynamic'))

    def __init__(self, name, note, link, date_from, date_to, milestone):
        self.name = name
        self.note = note
        self.link = link
        self.date_from = date_from
        self.date_to = date_to
        self.milestone = milestone
...

class Tag(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(255))
    reference = db.Column(db.String(255))

    def __init__(self, name, reference):
        self.name = name
        self.reference = reference
```

Comment: How do you try to update the tags?

Comment: Hi @dim - I've tried half a dozen ways, none of them work. That's what I want to know.

Comment: It's hard to tell you what's wrong when we don't know what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue here is that you need to specify the primary and secondary join. You can do it by swapping `tags = db.relationship('Tag', secondary=event_tag, backref=db.backref('events', lazy='dynamic'))` by the following.

```
tags = db.relationship(
    'Tag',
    secondary=event_tag,
    primaryjoin="event_tag.c.event_id == Event.id",
    secondaryjoin="event_tag.c.tag_id == Tag.id",
    backref=db.backref('events', lazy='dynamic'),
    lazy="dynamic"
)
```